# Styling PayPal dropdown menu

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, paypal

I'm trying to customize the look of PayPals buttons and dropdown menus, but I can't figure out how to style the dropdown menu?
Can this even be done?

```
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="BNG39UCNQW5YE">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="SIZES"></td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
    <option value="SMALL">SMALL </option>
    <option value="MEDIUM">MEDIUM </option>
    <option value="LARGE">LARGE </option>
</select> </td></tr>
</table>
<input type="image" src="http://www.dwste.com/images/buy_btn_pink.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/craigzilla/LRr5K/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the select box with `.os0 {styles_here}`

See this page for styling select boxes:

http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread the HTML. Instead of .os0 {} use select[name=os0]

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can't style a dropdown menu of a select input perfectly.

The best sollution: http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/

Not working in Opera - No arrow

jQuery (Example 1): http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/04/custom-drop-down-list-styling/

Not working without JS

CSS3: http://lea.verou.me/2011/03/custom-select-drop-downs-with-css3/

Not working properly in IE and Opera - Arrow not clickable